# Relative layout bottom align issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to implement a relative layout, similar to below picture.
But when trying to bottom align the bottom-right text view, it goes out of the screen.

What is the best/minimal way to design below layout?[image]

Code, currently I'm trying:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dash1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/view_subdash_top_right"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_name" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_instrument_change"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_text2"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="text1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_text2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="text2" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/view_subdash_top_right"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:text="name" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/dash1"
        android:gravity="top" >

        <!-- Here to enter bottom left -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_bottom_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:text="bottom right" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show your xml what u tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_top_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/rel_top_right"
            android:text="Top Left Text" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_top_right"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_top_left" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_top_text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Top Text1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_top_text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_top_text1"
                android:text="Top Text2" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rel_top"
        android:gravity="top" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_bottom_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/rel_bottom_left"
            android:text="Bottom Right Text" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_bottom_left"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tv_bottom_right" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_bottom_text1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bottom Text1" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_bottom_text2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_bottom_text1"
                android:text="Bottom Text2" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fill up the whole screen with those views, I'd use weighted LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <View
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="4"/>

             <View
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1">

             <View
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="1"/>

             <View
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="4"/>
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: actually, I have to achieve this with relative layout.

Comment: Sorry, was confused by your diagram, it looked like you wanted to fill the whole screen with those views, not sure if that is the case. If you are looking for top align and bottom align using relative layouts, the other answer is good